# Mongoose: how to update *all* persons matching a condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have do do something like this (please forgive me about the stupidity of the example... :-):

```
var dateRef = new Date(1990, 1, 1);
Person
  .where('dateOfBirth').gte(dateRef)
  .update({ $set: { isYoung: true } }, function (err, count) {
  })
;
```

I.e.: I'd like to $set to `true` field `isYoung` for every Person document whose date of birth (`dateOfBirth`) is later than a reference date.

My code is working for just **one** person, even if (currently) many documents do match the condition (all young people, here... :-).

Any clue?

---

P.S.: as a bonus, I'd like to set *not*-matching persons `isYoung` field to `false`, too, if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `multi:true` in update to update multiple documents like :

```
var dateRef = new Date(1990, 1, 1);
Person
  .where('dateOfBirth').gte(dateRef)
  .update({ $set: { isYoung: true } },{multi: true}, function (err, count) {
  });
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Call Person.update(...) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876655/update-of-multiple-documents-with-mongoose-fails/33879548#33879548