# Update of multiple documents with mongoose fails

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I try to update multiple documents with mongoose (3.8.37), but no document is updated.

I've done all things, that I've learned from other questions (see below):

- Use a callback function
- Specify multi:true

My update statement:

```
    Animal.where({ type: type}).update({deleted:1}, { multi: true, overwrite: true }, function (err,doc) {
        console.log("updates: "+doc);
    });
```

> updates: 0

When I just count the documents, I'll get a result.
=> The query is correct

```
    Animal.where({type: type}).count(function (err,doc) {
        console.log("count: "+doc);
    });
```

> count: 299

When I omit the multi:true option, the first record is updated.
=> The update statement is correct, too

```
    Animal.where({ type: type}).update({deleted:-1}, function (err,doc) {
        console.log("updates: "+doc);
    });
```

> updates: 1

So where's the error?

There are several questions dealing with this topic. Unfortunately none of these solves my problem.

- [how can i update multiple documents in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694507/how-can-i-update-multiple-documents-in-mongoose)
- [Mongoose update multiple documents doesn't update anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146244/mongoose-update-multiple-documents-doesnt-update-anything)
- [Mongoose: how to update *all* persons matching a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821070/mongoose-how-to-update-all-persons-matching-a-condition?lq=1)

** UPDATE

I've [added a log callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762264/log-all-queries-that-mongoose-fire-in-the-application) and discovered that no query to the mongodb is executed as long as the options (multi:true) are specified.

Comment: Try to change your `.update({deleted:1},...` to `.update({ $set: { deleted:1}},{multi: true}, function...`

Comment: @Molda Thanks for the tip. But I've already tried that. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup small example which works as expected, first i called `start()` to create some users then `update()`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); //v4.2.7

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    deleted: Number,
    name: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/user');

//start();

function start(){

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var user = new User({
            deleted: 1,
            name: i
        }); 
        user.save(); 
        console.log('user ---> ', user);      
    };

    User.find({}, function(err, docs){
        console.log('found ---> ', err, docs);
    });

}

update();

function update (){
    User.update({deleted:1}, {$set: {deleted: 0}}, {multi:true}, function(err, numAffected){
        console.log('updated ---> ', err, numAffected);
    });
}
```

I'm not sure why update doesn't work with `where(...)`

```
function update (){
    // this doesn't work
    User.where({deleted:1}).update({$set: {deleted: 0}}, {multi:true}, function(err, numAffected){
        console.log('updated ---> ', err, numAffected);
    });
}
```

Comment: Great! Works: User.where().update() Doesn't work: User.where().update(multi:true) => Conclusion: Always use User.update() as Molda suggests!